# C++ Sigsegv on setting member variables

Tags: c++

I have a deque of shared pointers that I want to copy

```
void setMyStuff(std::deque<std::shared_ptr<MyClassBase>> d_items, SomeSmartClassPtr x ) {
    m_d_items = d_items; /// First segfault
    m_x = x; /// works fine if I skip above line
    m_s = MyStruct(); /// Second Segfault
    m_p_s = std::shared_ptr<MyStruct>( m_s ); /// Third Segfault

}
std::deque<std::shared_ptr<MyClassBase>> m_d_items;
SomeSmartClassPtr m_x;
MyStruct() m_s;
std::shared_ptr<MyStruct> m_p_s;;
}

struct MyStruct{
    public:        
    MyStruct() {}
    long m_a=0, m_b=0;
    std::shared_ptr<SomethingElse> p_c;
```

Everything builds fine, but when I run the code it produces a segmentation fold in the line where I set m_d_items.

Stacktrace looks as follows. Any suggestions what the issue could be?

```
1  __copy_m<std::shared_ptr<MyClassBase> *, std::shared_ptr<MyClassBase> *>              stl_algobase.h        336  0x7ffff693ea18 
2  __copy_move_a<false, std::shared_ptr<MyClassBase> *, std::shared_ptr<MyClassBase> *>  stl_algobase.h        396  0x7ffff693ea18 
3  __copy_move_a2<false, std::shared_ptr<MyClassBase> *, std::shared_ptr<MyClassBase> *> stl_algobase.h        434  0x7ffff693ea18 
4  copy<std::shared_ptr<MyClassBase> *, std::shared_ptr<MyClassBase> *>                  stl_algobase.h        466  0x7ffff693ea18 
5  std::copy<std::shared_ptr<MyClassBase>>                                               deque.tcc             959  0x7ffff693ea18 
6  std::deque<std::shared_ptr<MyClassBase>>::operator=                                   deque.tcc             100  0x7ffff6947930
```

doing this works without problems:

```
 for ( auto i : d_items) {
    m_d_items.push_back( i );
}
```

but then it breaks again when assigning MyStruct()

```
1  std::_Sp_counted_base<(__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::_M_release shared_ptr_base.h     146  0x4f553e       
2  ~__shared_count                                               shared_ptr_base.h     666  0x7ffff693db34 
3  ~__shared_ptr                                                 shared_ptr_base.h     914  0x7ffff693db34 
4  operator=                                                     shared_ptr_base.h     993  0x7ffff693db34 
5  operator=                                                     shared_ptr.h          291  0x7ffff693db34 
6  operator=                                                     MyStruct.h            15   0x7ffff693db34
```

I dont understand why the stack trace at teh assignment of MyStruct() even goes to shared_ptr_base as I dont create a shared pointer, yet.

This* is not nullptr. I am running this on qtcreator, gcc, c++11

Any clues what is broken here?

EDIT: 
Barmar has been pointing out that the second segfault comes at teh destructor of the shared pointer. So I removed std::shared_ptr p_c from MyStruct and now it breaks at the creation of the shared pointer

```
m_p_s = std::shared_ptr<MyStruct>( m_s )

1  std::_Sp_counted_base<(__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::_M_release shared_ptr_base.h     146  0x4f553e
```

So it seems to want to destruct my shared pointers although I dont expect/want that to happen

Comment: You're assigning a `std::deque` whose elements are `std::shared_ptr`. It has to copy the elements, so it goes into `shared_ptr_base`.

Comment: I meant at the second place where it comes up with a segmentation fault, the assignment of MyStruct(). Edited to make that clearer

Comment: You haven't shown the `MyStruct` class, but it looks like it includes a `shared_ptr` member. The second stack trace shows that the error is happening in the destructor of a shared pointer.

Comment: yes, it does include a shared pointer

Comment: Then why don't you think it should go into `shared_ptr_base` when it's copying that?

Comment: Now that you mention that, I dont think that anymore

Comment: So both errors seem to be related to using shared pointers incorrectly. You need to post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the problem. It's impossible to tell what's wrong from the snippet you've posted.

Comment: Just one last question... any idea why it possible would destruct the shared pointers in MyStruct right after at its creation?

Comment: It might be a temporary object created during the assignment. Without seeing your assignment operator, it's hard to know. That's why you need to post enough code to reproduce the problem.